# MySql Order By with Conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following fields.

```
Table
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| id | title | approve | expirydate |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
```

I want to filter rows by expirydate, in that i want get rows first which have expirydate far away from today (Descending order of expirydate field) and if any row haven't 'expirydate' or it is already expired order by Descending order of id field.

example (assume today == 2015-01-15)

```
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| id | title | approve | expirydate |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 1  | ttle1 | 1       | 2015-01-01 |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 2  | ttle2 | 1       | 2015-02-15 |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 3  | ttle3 | 1       |            |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 4  | ttle4 | 1       | 2015-01-20 |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
```

expected result

```
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 2  | ttle2 | 1       | 2015-02-15 |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 4  | ttle4 | 1       | 2015-01-20 |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 3  | ttle3 | 1       |            |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| 1  | ttle1 | 1       | 2015-01-01 |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
```

Is it possible to get values with these conditions in one MySQL query ?? I really don't have idea to do this.Any help gratefully received :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from `table` order by
    ifnull(expirydate>curdate(),0) desc,
    if(expirydate>curdate(),expirydate,null) desc,
    id desc
```

- `ifnull(expirydate>curdate(),0) desc` needed to place not expired before expired or with `null` in `expirydate`. `ifnull` needed to treat `null` in `expirydate` (`expirydate>curdate()` return `null`) same way as already expired (`expirydate>curdate()` return 0).
- `if(expirydate>curdate(),expirydate,null) desc` needed to order not expired by `expirydate` in descending order while not affect expired or with `null` in `expirydate` by providing same value for ordering (`null` in this case, but it can be any other valid value for given data type).
- `id desc` order by `id` in descending order. Affect expired or with `null` in `expirydate` and not expired with same `expirydate`.

Comment: thank you :) This query is work fine :) I think both 'ifnull' and 'if' statement do the same job.

Comment: @indrarajw They do different job. Maybe `ifnull(expirydate>curdate(),0) desc` redundant here. If `null` treated as being less then any not `null` value, then `if(expirydate>curdate(),expirydate,null) desc` place them to the bottom of the list, as you want. But, for example, if you want ascending ordering for not expired, but still place them before expired, then `ifnull(expirydate>curdate(),0) desc` should be present.

Answer (score 0):

I think some more data would help understand the structure, but would the following query return what you want?

Assuming your table name is `tbl`, then:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
tbl
order by - datediff(now(), coalesce(expirydate, now())) desc , id desc;
```

Comment: thank you for answer :) this answer helps me a lot to get my desire result. this is my edited query _"ORDER BY  DATEDIFF(
IF((`expirydate`<CURDATE() OR ISNULL(`expirydate`)), NOW(),`expirydate`), NOW()) DESC, `id` DESC"_

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, title, approve, expirydate FROM
(SELECT id, title, approve, expirydate
FROM tableName
WHERE expirydate > '2015-01-15'
ORDER BY expirydate DESC) AS t1

UNION

SELECT id, title, approve, expirydate FROM
(SELECT id,title, approve, expirydate
FROM tableName
WHERE expirydate < '2015-01-15' OR expirydate IS NULL
ORDER BY id DESC) AS t2
```

Comment: this query is little longer but its work for me :) thanx